# Clear readonly textarea selection when programmatically invoking blur?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a readonly textarea where text is programmatically added.

When I invoke `blur` on this element, any text that was selected in it remains selected.

Here's a demo:

```js
let ta = document.getElementById("ta")
ta.value="SELECT ME THEN PRESS A KEY!"
ta.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  ta.setSelectionRange(0, 0)
});
ta.addEventListener("keypress", () => {
  ta.blur() // <-- This should de-select text
})
```

```html
<textarea id="ta" readonly></textarea>
```

EDIT: Silly me, I'll fix this by invoking `setSelectionRange` before `blur`.

```js
    ta.addEventListener("keypress", () => {
      ta.setSelectionRange(0, 0)
      ta.blur()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `setSelectionRange` method, like so:

```js
myTextArea.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    myTextArea.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
});

myTextArea.textContent = `myTextArea.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    myTextArea.setSelectionRange(0, 0)
});`;

myTextArea.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
  myTextArea.dispatchEvent(new FocusEvent('blur'));
  myTextArea.blur();
});
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea" readonly></textarea>
```

added programatic `blur` by key, also please note the `keypress` event is  [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event), you should use `keydown` instead.

also, it seems that in Chrome `setSelectionRange` does not work when calling `blur()` for a `readonly` target, nevertheless the `blur` happens, but it works for a programmatically dispatched `blur` event on that target.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You didn't invoke `blur` programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, but still the text is not de-selected on keydown...

Comment: it's weird, seems to work only in firefox, cannot make it work in chrome, must try something else

Comment: finally made it, seems that chrome does not trigger `blur` event for `readonly` targets, so must trigger this event programmatically

Comment: Pretty sure Chrome triggers blur event for readonly targets, because I am using that event for other things (not just trying to deselect text) and it works fine. I think using `setSelectionRange` on an unfocused element is the real issue here...

Comment: you may be right, did some additional tests and seems to be so, another workaround may be to reset content, i.e. `text = myTextArea.textContent` `myTextArea.textContent = ''` `myTextArea.textContent = text`

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement), it is `myTextArea.setSelectionRange(0, 0)`

```
// (Text is selected in the textarea)
myTextArea.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    myTextArea.setSelectionRange(0, 0)
})
myTextArea.blur()
```

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/laruiss/ugnm62w3/20/)

Comment: No, `setSelectionRange` does not work. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h9j2bkyf/

Comment: It does not work in Chrome if the textarea is readonly (which was not mentioned in the first post), you are right. It does work, though, in Chrome if the textarea is not readonly, and always works in Firefox.